# How do I update the workspace while a script is running in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need my workspace to update every so often (like every X seconds) or (after a certain loop finishes).

Is there a command to update the workspace?

Added (4/1/11)  while a script is running (it takes like 10 mins to run), I want to see what the values of the variables in the Workspace are doing

Comment: +1, if you mean how to update content of the Workspace window on MATLAB desktop while a script is running. Am I right?

Comment: yes, while a script is running (it takes like 10 mins to run), I want to see what the values of the variables in the Workspace are doing.

Comment: I'd like this functionality to in a script that runs for hours/days - without having to muck up my output with unwanted display of values (I need it for for monitoring progress not debugging). In particular it doesn't even show updated workspace values when it stops on the input command. I even tried fprintf('%d\r',X); but the \r is treated like a \r\n contrary to the documentation, and \r\n or \n\r actually prints as \r\n\r\n. R2014a on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the exact answer to your question. I don't think it's possible, unless some undocumented feature exists.

I would advise you to use [**WHOS**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/who.html) function to display workspace variables in run-time. You can do it not every iteration. Here is an example code to illustrate the point:

```
ivector=[];
for ii=1:100
    ivector = [ivector ii];
    pause(0.01)
    if mod(ii,20)==0 %# do whos every 20th iteration
        whos
    end
end
```

You can show only certain variables with `whos ivector`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put the semi-colon at the end, and it will print whatever variable:

```
while flag==0,
flux=flux*(1/(1-reactivity))
n=n+1;
if n>=20,
    flag=1;
end
```

This will display flux every time it loops.